# DyanmoDB: not getting the answer I'm expecting using batch_get_item

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a batch_get_item to request multiple items from a table. I am following the PHP example in the DynamoDB documentation, but I am not getting the results I'm expecting.

Following is the code:

```
$batch_array = array ();
$batch_array[]= array ('HashKeyElement'  =>
 array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => 'V1L3M5O5L1W8R5B6D2Q1S8V0B3R8M7A6R0X0'));

$options = array (
    'RequestItems' => array(
        'profile_dev' => array (
            'Keys' => $batch_array
            )
    )
);

$result = $this->db->batch_get_item($options);
```

Instead of getting the data, I am getting a very long response, and I'm including the relevant information from the tail end of it:

```
[x-aws-body] => {"RequestItems":{"profile_dev":{"Keys":[{"HashKeyElement":{"S":"V1L3M5O5L1W8R5B6D2Q1S8V0B3R8M7A6R0X0"}}]}}} ) [body] => CFSimpleXML Object ( [__type] => com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException [message] => One or more parameter values were invalid: The provided key size does not match with that of the schema ) [status] => 400 ) )
```

The hashKey for this table is a string. It has a rangeKey, but I am using the hashKey so I can get all the rows matching the hashKey. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The DynamoDB documentation (and SDK samples) have colossal bugs in them. The documentation, and actual SDK code, make use only of the hashKeyElement, but in fact if a table has both a hashKey AND a rangeKey, both must be used.

When I used both the hashKey and the rangeKey, the call worked.

Comment: Yes, they have terrible docs in some points. The API docs for getItem indicate that with hash-range both things must be given to get an item. I'm yet to figure a good use case for this kind of keys given this unadvertised constraint.

Comment: @DavidPelaez To get a single item you need to provide both, but to get a set of items, you can query on the first and get all items that matched ordered based on the second.

Answer (score 1):

Get (or batch get) requires you to completely define the key of all items you are getting. If you want to retrieve all rows with the same hashKey using a single call, it seems like you're looking for Query.

Comment: No, I'm looking for items matching various hashKeys. Query is used for other purposes and query works on a single table.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `BatchGet`, you should be using `Query`. Here is an example using the PHP SDK to get all items with the HASH key 'YourHashKey' on table 'YourTable'

```
// Instantiate the class
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();

$response = $dynamodb->query(array(
    'TableName' => 'YourTable', 
        'HashKeyValue' => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => 'YourHashKey' ),
));
```

Reference: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPQuerying.html

Comment: No, I'm looking specifically for usage of BatchGetItem. I'm retrieving multiple items that do not match the same hashKey and possibly from different tables. I provided the answer. The Amaazon SDK and sample code were wrong.

Comment: There is no 'BatchQuery', only 'BatchGet', GET means you know the HASH and RANGE. BatchQuery would be a cool feature, but it doesn't exist. Nothing is incorrect in the docs or the PHP SDK, maybe not as clear as it could be, but not incorrect.

Comment: Also, if you are using EC2 in the same region as DynamoDB the return trip is less than 4ms, so using a BATCH function doesn't really make much of a difference to firing off multiple requests.

Comment: You are wrong on all counts. DynamoDB documentation, page 134: $batch_get_response = $dynamodb->batch_get_item(array(
    'RequestItems' => array(
        'Forum' => array(
            'Keys' => array(
                array( // Key #2
                    'HashKeyElement'  => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING =>
 'Amazon DynamoDB' )

Comment: I also don't know why you would bring up a hypothetical BatchQuery, as in query, you can use a hashkey or a hashkey and a range key

Comment: Lastly, it may be a 4ms round trip, but for 5,000 queries, that adds up to 20secs. Yet, you feel free to ding my answer. Does 20 seconds per query, when you're using a mobile device sound right to you?